# Merging yarn.lock to existing pnpm.lock

Tags: yarnpkg, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

There are two repos with ts projects: one based on Yarn, another one PNPM with multiple workspaces.
I need to make the first one a part of the second, as one more workspace.

When I put `yarn.lock` (from the first repo) to the PNPM repo, and do `pnpm import`, the `pnpm-lock.yaml` messes up. Other workspaces stop to build.

The another option I am thinking to try is migrating that repo from Yarn to PNPM first, and then try to merge (as it might be easier with two pnpm-lock.yaml file, idk)

So asking some experts out here who dealt with similar use case.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the file "mess up" when you do a pnpm import?